# Adjusting the width of columns of all tables in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, tabular

In my Word document, I have over 300 tables and I want to change the table style and adjust the columns' widths. I am using the following code in my VBA macro. It's working for a style but not for column width. Please help me find where the problem is.

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Variable"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=4, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Tables(1).Style = "eo_tabelle_2"
    With Tables(1).Spacing
     .Item(1) = 5.5 'adjusts width of text box 1 in cm
     .Item(2) = 8.5 'adjusts width of text box 2 in cm
     .Item(3) = 7.5 'adjusts width of text box 3 in cm
     .Item(4) = 1.1 'adjusts width of text box 4 in cm
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to interpret your question literally: that you merely want to process all the tables in the document and that your code is using `Find` only in order to locate a table...

The following example shows how you can work with the underlying objects in Word directly, rather than relying on the current Selection, which is what the macro recorder gives you.

So, at the beginning we declare object variables for the Document and a Table. The current document with the focus is assigned to the first. Then, with `For Each...Next` we can loop through each Table object in that document and perform the same actions on each one.

In this case, the style is specified and the column widths set. Note that in order to give a column width in centimeters it's necessary to use a built-in conversion function `CentimetersToPoints` since Word measures column width in Points.

```
Sub FormatTables
  Dim doc as Document
  Dim tbl as Table

  Set doc = ActiveDocument
  For Each tbl in doc.Tables
    tbl.Style = "eo_tabelle_2"
    tbl.Columns(1).Width = CentimetersToPoints(5.5)
    tbl.Columns(2).Width = CentimetersToPoints(8.5)
    tbl.Columns(3).Width = CentimetersToPoints(7.5)
    tbl.Columns(4).Width = CentimetersToPoints(1.1)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help, but it seems like the width command works without columns arguments. but with arguments its give error.

Comment: i am receiving error 5941 for Colomns 2,3 and 4. can you please help me out why is it so... thank you

Comment: @UsmanBhinder What's the text of the error? The number doesn't tell me anything...

Comment: @UsmanBhinder I made a small correction to the code, but it had nothing to do with the columns, like you report. Does your table have four columns?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can recall all the tables in a word file are a part of  `Tables` collection and we can access the individual table item using an index. Assuming that you wont know the number of tables, here's the code that works for me.

```
For Each tbl In Doc.Tables
      tbl.Columns(3).Width = 40
Next
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your answers, but the tbl.Columns(1).Width = CentimetersToPoints(5.5)

Comment: Haha, Nice observation mate. I just missed that. I hope that apart from that minor miss, I was able to help you with your query.